# More Like This Query Not Getting Serialized - NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to create an Elasticsearch MLT query using NEST's object initializer syntax. However, the final query when serialized, is ONLY missing the MLT part of it. Every other query is present though.

When inspecting the query object, the MLT is present. It's just not getting serialized.

I wonder what I may be doing wrong.

I also noticed that when I add Fields it works. But I don't believe fields is a mandatory property here that when it is not set, then the MLT query is ignored.

The MLT query is initialized like this;

```
new MoreLikeThisQuery
        {
            Like = new[]
            {
                new Like(new MLTDocProvider
                {
                    Id = parameters.Id
                }), 
            }
        }
```

`MLTDocProvider` implements the `ILikeDocument` interface.

I expect the serialized query to contain the MLT part, but it is the only part that is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the *conditionless* behaviour of more like this query in NEST; I've [opened an issue to address](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3696). In the meantime, you can get the desired behaviour by marking the `MoreLikeThisQuery` as verbatim, which will override NEST's conditionless behaviour

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var parameters = new 
{
    Id = 1
};


var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Document>
{
    Query = new MoreLikeThisQuery
    {
        Like = new[]
        {
            new Like(new MLTDocProvider
            {
                Id = parameters.Id
            }),
        },
        IsVerbatim = true
    }
};

var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(searchRequest);
```

which serializes as

```
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "like": [
        {
          "_id": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Good to know about the `IsVerbatim` property.

Comment: @SumatanJunior this is now fixed in 6.7.0: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/6.7.0

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.